# Will sleep() in script A allow script B to run?

Tags: php, performance, cpu, sleep

I have a number of scripts that run many times every day. Some run every 5 minutes, others every 10, 15, 60 minutes etc. Most of the scripts are dealing with large amounts of data, where they loop through and process each row.

My host's cron does not allow me to decide when each script starts, I can only choose the number of minutes apart, so the scripts that run every 5 minutes, run at 00,05,10,15...
and the scripts that run every 10 minutes run at 00,10,20,30...
etc.

That means a lot of scripts start running at 00.

That wouldn't really be a problem except for the fact that the server is also used by regular users that often only need to do something that shouldn't take a lot of time. But if they happen to be doing it when a lot of those scripts are running, everything slows down and they are not able to do even those simple things without waiting for a long time.

I read somewhere that the sleep function would stop the CPU from processing data and allow smaller tasks to run. Do you know if that is the case? If I were to insert a sleep(1) after each loop in a lot of these scripts, would that improve the performance that is seen by individual users doing small tasks, i.e. allow them to skip the line?

Example
Script A that runs every 5 minutes

```
foreach ($a_hundred_things as $one_thing) {
  do_this($one_thing);
  // would adding sleep(1); here improve performance?
}
```

Script B that runs when a user clicks a button

```
do_this_thing_that_only_takes_a_minute();
```

At the moment, if a script like Script A (and many others like it) is running, the user will sometimes have to wait a long time (few minutes) for Script B to run. I'd like B to be able to somehow take priority as that's something that cannot wait, while the automatic scripts can afford to be delayed.

Would adding the sleep(1) in Script A (and all other similar scripts running at the same time) improve the performance?
I know I could try to test it, but there are a lot of scripts involved and this doesn't seem to happen every time.

Comment: sleep suspends the thread, and the CPU doesn't allocate time on a suspended thread. But this approach will significantly increase the running time of your script.

Comment: Change provider to one who gives you more control over crontab.

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă Thanks for the info. It's fine if the running time is increased if users will be able to do their thing without delay.

Comment: @MarkusZeller That's not an option at the moment. But I've thought about using a cron service from a third party.

Comment: It's not an option doing things dirty when can be done elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, `usleep()` let you specify how many *microseconds* you want to sleep for, and is the superior function.

The following are kludges, but can help soften the blow while you implement a better solution:

1. Insert a random wait of a few seconds at the beginning of a cron so that they don't all start up at once. This prevents your machine getting completely *slammed* every 15 minutes while everything's intializing at once.

   ```
   usleep(mt_rand(0,10000000));
   ```
2. Ghetto throttling. Measure the time it takes to perform one loop iteration, then sleep for that long. You've effectively cut performance in half.

   ```
   while($condition) {
     $start = microtime(true);
     // do work
     usleep( (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000000) );
   }
   ```

*Actual* solutions that you should work on, note that these are not mutually exclusive:

1. Farm off periodic/async tasks to one or more other machines. There's no reason to negatively impact the performance of user-facing infrastructure with work that has no direct bearing on user requests.
2. Use a queue/worker model for async tasks, and only use cron to periodically submit jobs for processing. This would roughly equate to:

   1. Create a generalized worker process.
   2. Set up a task queue. [I recommend AMQP-compatible queue systems, and personally prefer RabbitMQ]
   3. Spin up one or more worker processes, something like Supervisord makes it simple to keep a small herd of workers running.

Oops! You've implemented both of those? That's called "Horizontal Scaling" and how we build modern apps in 2020. Now you can spin up machines and processes on-demand and as-needed, maybe even automatically. Sorry for the convenience. `:P`